# Python equivalent of R assign

Tags: python

In R, I can use [assign](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) to assign a value to a name in environment on the fly (rather than `<-`.

Example:

```
> assign('x', 1)
> x
[1] 1
```

Does Python has an equivalent to assign rather than `=`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Python equivalent to R's `assign()` is assignment to `globals()`:

```
globals()['x'] = 1
```

But you should not do this, because it is a sign of poor code in 99% of cases.  If you want to store values by name, use a `dict`:

```
stuff = {}
stuff['x'] = 1
```

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank: Sure, but then the name is not a variable.  You don't need `assign()` in R to assign a value to a name which is directly specified in the code.

Answer (score 2):

What is also possible to do, but for security reasons less recommended, is the use of `eval` and `exec`:

```
exec('x = 1')
eval('x')
eval('x + 5')
exec('y = x + 5')
eval('y')
```

Instead if you have classes and/or class instances, I recommend using `setattr` and `getattr`:

```
class A():
    pass
a = A()
setattr(a, 'x', 999)
a.x  # returns 999
getattr(a, 'x')  # same as a.x
A.x  # raises AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'x', since x is instance variable
setattr(A, 'x', 99)  # assign class variable
A.x  # returns 99
a.x  # still returns 999! --> instance variable
```

What is a quite important point here: Setting the class variable will not overwrite the instance variable.