# Python equivalent of R assign inside a function

Tags: python, r, variables, assign

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747277/python-equivalent-of-r-assign) but slightly different.

How can I do R's `assign()` inside a function?

I tried `locals()['x'] = 3` but failed.
I tried `exec('x=3')` but also failed.

How can I access a function's namespace and modify it when I only have string variable that contains the variable name.

on eshirvana's request, I put down the result of `exec()` inside a function

```
def f():
    exec('a=3')
    print(a)

f()
# NameError                                 Traceback (most recent # call last)
# Input In [64], in <module>
# ----> 1 f()
#
# Input In [63], in f()
#       1 def f():
#       2     exec('a=3')
# ----> 3     print(a)
# 
# NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: why exec() failed? explain better and with detail

Comment: You cannot dynamically create local variables in CPython, at least, there is no interface to do that (there is nothing except your imagination preventing you from trying various hacks). That is ok, because there is **never a good reason to**. Just use a `dict` or some *other container*. Dynamically creating variables is almost always a bad idea.